# Qt app geometry width too big

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I nuked the default window from my GUI app and tried to re-implement things like maximize when dragging window to top and dragging it left and right to take half a screen.

The latter is giving me some problems, the width of the app is not half the screen but more than that (like 100px more). The height is good tho.

```
void MainWindow::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
  QPoint curPos = event->globalPos();
  if (this->ui->labelTitle->underMouse()) //we grabbed the top bar
  {
    if (curPos.x()<2) //x below 2px, left side of screen
    {
          this->setGeometry(QRect(
                                QPoint(0,0), //top-left
                                QSize(
                                    QApplication::desktop()->availableGeometry().right()/2, 
                                    QApplication::desktop()->availableGeometry().bottom())));
    }
    QWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
}
```

My screen res is 1600x900
`.right()` is 1599 and `.right()/2` is 799 but the actual app width becomes 900 for some reason. Where am I failing?

Comment: do not fight with the framework! Do not change yourself geometry of  main window (from that window). First of all you should describe what you are trying achieve. I'm pretty sure it can be achieved in some simple way without doing this strange thing. Do you use layout in central widget (this probably limits the size of main window)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that window minimum size policy was set to 900px.